# Progress bar for back end python programs on Django or other web frameworks

Tags: python, django

I've been searching and iterating a lot recently trying to figure out how to have a real time progress bar on the webpage to show the progress of programs running at the backend at the server.

Right now I'm using Django for building the website as I need to run python programs on the server. So far when the web user click "submit" button, it will take the python program (written in views.py) about one minute to present the result and having a progress bar can really help here.

Hope I provided enough detail about my question and thank you in advance for any one who can help.

Comment: I'd imagine you could have the server send data through a websocket – as it progresses through its routines. The client could then employ the data to update the UI's progress bar.

Comment: The problem is that the backend program will not communicate with the socket until it completes the job. I have to make a python definition of the program within views.py and the definition will return result only after completing the task.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a background task and use AJAX for pulling the current status and present it to the user.

Take a look at the celery project: http://www.celeryproject.org/.

It may help you manage your background tasks and works great with django!

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks. I started with using Celery to make this feature. It would be nice to have a sample website using Celery or whatever package to have a real time status bar on the page. It's hard for me to "invent" something due to my humble programming experience